# Obligatorily share public content on facebook with ShareLinkContent

Tags: android, facebook

Is possible to share content on Facebook obligatorily public?

I need to check that the user shares real content, but now we can share content on **private mode**, so I need handle this, cause is a **invalid share**.

Im using the facebook sdk with ShareLinkContent.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: No, of course you can not force that - that is the user’s decision. And what does “I need to check that the user shares real content” even mean? How would content be “unreal” or “invalid”?

Comment: @CBroe Invalid if is not public

Comment: Why? I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward users in any way, shape or form for posting your content.

Comment: @CBroe I know, the user will win prizes sharing public content

Comment: That is not allowed! You need to go and read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy)